# Do Hydrinos Exist?

Tags: fusion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Have the Rowan University “hydrino” findings been replicated elsewhere?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/2392/have-the-rowan-university-hydrino-findings-been-replicated-elsewhere)

I came across this controversial company: [Black Light Power](http://blacklightpower.com/)
I want to know if there is any validity of the scientific claims made by this company and its founder Dr. Mills - especially concerning the existence of "hydrinos."

Comment: Get some basic introduction to the hydrinos e.g. at http://motls.blogspot.com/2005/11/hydrinos.html - it's complete nonsense about a "new sub-ground state of the Hydrogen atom". It starts with denying the uncertainty principle, for no good reason except for dreaming about childish nonsensical sources of energy. The whole research is fraud and the guy has actually collected tens of millions of dollars for this pseudoscience. Rowan University is harboring lots of these pseudoscientists, including Shahriar Afshar who has claimed to "disprove the complementarity principle" - also nonsense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this stuff is complete balderdash.  It is nonsense of the first degree.

Comment: In case anyone's interested, I tried to explain why the hydrino stuff is crackpot on my blog: http://blog.richmond.edu/physicsbunn/2008/11/17/hydrinos-on-the-radio/ and http://blog.richmond.edu/physicsbunn/2008/11/22/thomas-bayes-says-that-i-shouldnt-believe-in-hydrinos/

Comment: This is a poor answer.  Can you give some *reasons* why it's balderdash?

Comment: While in general it's true that this would be a poor answer, given that the question is closed as a duplicate, I don't think it matters much. The explanation would be provided at the linked duplicate question.