# Transition of H to hydrino H(1/4) by HOH as the catalyst

Tags: hydrogen

Is this real, is there a more stable form of Hydrogen atom?

Source :
Mechanism of Soft X-ray Continuum Radiation from Low-Energy Pinch Discharges of Hydrogen and Ultra-low Field Ignition of Solid Fuels
– R. Mills, J. Lotoski, Y. Lu, submitted.

EUV radiation in the 10-30 nm region observed only arising from very low energy pulsed pinch gas discharges comprising some hydrogen first at BlackLight Power, Inc. (BLP) and reproduced at the Harvard Center for Astrophysics (CfA) was determined to be due to the transition of H to the lower-energy hydrogen or hydrino state H(1/4) whose emission matches that observed wherein alternative sources were eliminated.

Existence of the transition of H to hydrino H(1/4) by HOH as the catalyst.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2392/2451

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe this just came up.  I was just looking at this stuff two hours ago.  A number of scientists have concluded that Mills' analysis is wrong.  I'm not aware of independent support for Mills.

You can see what people have to say [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackLight_Power).

Comment: Thanks for criticism link will review later. Also what about "reproduced at the Harvard Center for Astrophysics" any info on the reproduction results.

Comment: From CNN Article http://ireport.cnn.com/docs/DOC-530712   "Working with a team headed by Dr. Alexander Bykanov at Harvard's Smithsonian Center for Astrophysics under contract with GEN3 Partners, the device showed hydrogen spectral emissions below 80 nanometers, the previously known "ground state" of hydrogen."

Answer (score 0):

As of Oct. 28th, it appears that the answer is now true. At a conference for investors and industry partners, Mills has publicly presented a device that uses this process to produce extraordinary heat (over 2700K) using only H -> H[1/4] reactant. Incredibly, the device can produce a self-sustaining plasma for minutes without a source of charged particles. This is unknown in terrestrial applications. See timestamp 04:30 in the [link](http://youtu.be/jUBheBH9eio?t=265) when the ignition current is turned off.